# DataBinding with datatriggers XAML with Boolean Local Variable

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatrigger

I am having trouble getting my tabitem to flash when the value for newCall is true. I think i have the Xaml correct but i am not sure how to bind it behind in code.  When the variable new Call is set to true i would like my tabitem to flash.

```
<TabItem.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTabItem}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="flashAnimation" >
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:0.5" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
            </Storyboard>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding newCall}" Value="True">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Name="flash" Storyboard="{StaticResource flashAnimation}" />
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TabItem.Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ViewModel has to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. In the ViewModel add the following Code:

```
private bool _newCall;

    public bool newCall
    {
        get { return _newCall; }
        set
        { 
            _newCall = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("newCall"));
            }
        }
    }
```

and change `Binding="{Binding newCall}` to `Binding="{Binding newCall, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Then, the TabItem will start flashing as soon as newCall is set to true